# Variables becomes undefined outside of function

Tags: javascript, leaflet

So I've been using leaflet.js to create a map of vaccination sites in my home state and was trying to use routing to find the closest site to the user, but the variable somehow becomes undefined when I log or try to call it outside the function. I'm relatively new to js and learned about leaflet when using folium in python. In python I think you would just declare you're changing a global variable or better yet use return but I'm not really sure how to do that with js and the leaflet library.

```
var self_lat;
var self_long;
...
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([34.7465, -92.2896], 6);
...
function onLocationFound(e) {
    console.log(e);
    self_lat =  e.latitude;
    self_long = e.longitude;
    L.marker([e.latitude, e.longitude], {icon: home_marker}).bindPopup("YOU ARE HERE!").addTo(mymap);
    console.log(typeof(e.latitude))
    console.log(typeof(e.longitude))
}

function onLocationError(e) {
    alert(e.message);
}
mymap.locate({setView: false, maxZoom: 16});
mymap.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
mymap.on('locationerror', onLocationError);

...
L.Routing.control({
waypoints: [
L.latLng([self_lat, self_long]),
L.latLng([34.7465, -92.2896])
]
}).addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: `map.on('locationFound', onLocationFound){...` is _not_ the correct syntax here. Either provide a callback handler, or provide a callback function, but you cannot do both at the same time.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: You have edited the code so that you only provide a handler - that is one way (and should work fine). The other way is to use an inline function to do the same thing like this (using an "arrow function"): `mymap.on('locationfound', ()=>{/* do stuff here */ });`

Comment: Doesn't work in its current state. When I currently run it it says self_lat and self_long are still undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the problem here, add a `console.log( 'Calling L.Routing.control()', self_lat, self_long )` call just before the `L.Routing.control()` call (where you have `...` in the code listing).

You will notice two things:

1. As you already know, `self_lat` and `self_long` will be `undefined` here. But why?
2. You will also see that this new `console.log()` is called *before* the existing `console.log()` calls where you log these values inside the `onLocationFound` function. And that is the root of the problem.

Like many similar functions in other JavaScript libraries and native JavaScript itself, Leaflet's `myMap.on( eventName, eventListener )` function is *asynchronous*. That means the `eventListener` - in this case, `onLocationFound` - is not called immediately. It is called sometime later, *after* the `myMap.on()` call itself has returned.

All asynchronous callback/listener functions in JavaScript work this way. Setting a global is rarely useful, because the problem is *when* the various bits of code get run.

Without knowing the rest of your code, one possible fix I might suggest would be to get rid of the `self_lat` and `self_long` variables entirely, and move the `L.Routing.control()` call *inside* your `onLocationFound` function, like this:

```js
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([34.7465, -92.2896], 6);
...
function onLocationFound(e) {
    console.log(e);
    L.marker(
        [e.latitude, e.longitude],
        {icon: home_marker}
    ).bindPopup("YOU ARE HERE!").addTo(mymap);

    L.Routing.control({
        waypoints: [
            L.latLng([e.latitude, e.longitude]),
            L.latLng([34.7465, -92.2896])
        ]
    }).addTo(mymap);
}

function onLocationError(e) {
    alert(e.message);
}
mymap.locate({setView: false, maxZoom: 16});
mymap.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
mymap.on('locationerror', onLocationError);
```

Here is a very simple example that will help illustrate. We make a `setTimeout()` call and three `console.log()` calls: one before, one after, and one inside the callback. Click the Run button below and note the order of the log messages:

```js
console.log( 'Before setTimeout' );
setTimeout(
    function() {
        console.log( 'Inside setTimeout callback' );
    },
    1  // one millisecond delay
);
console.log( 'After setTimeout returns' );
```

Of course the name `setTimeout()` makes it more clear that there will be delay (even if it's just a millisecond) before the callback function is called. The thing to note is that *all* asynchronous callback functions and event listeners in JavaScript work like this.

Comment: Ah ok thank you. Is there any way I could make it synchronous or save it some other way? I want to use routing control to find the distance and time from your location to all vaccination locations and plot the best one.

Comment: JavaScript does have a way to make a remote request like this synchronous, but I don't know if this Leaflet API supports it. In any case, you shouldn't use it, as it locks up the entire browser while waiting for the server response: the user can't even close the page if the server doesn't respond.

Comment: There is a way to make JavaScript code feel more like synchronous code like you would write in Python: `async`/`await`. If the Leaflet map's `on` method returns a `Promise`, this would be pretty easy to implement. I still suggest getting familiar with the old-fashioned technique where you do everything in the event listener function (or in a function that calls, same thing either way), as it will help with understanding how asynchronous code works.

Answer (score 0):

If `self_lat` and `self_long` are not global variables, you are loosing the context by passing only the prototype of `onLocationFound`, the function is being called in the context of `mymap` where those variables do not exist, to solve this **and keep your callback as a separate function** you could call it as follows:

```
mymap.on('locationfound', (e) => onLocationFound(e));
```

Comment: I've tried it and it doesn't seem to work. When I currently run it it says self_lat and self_long are still undefined.

Comment: hmmm, weird, that means your variables are actually declared in a different context other than the one you are instantiating the map, are you using any framework to execute this or it is only a plain javascript file?

Comment: thinking... there is a probability that your issue is not about your callbacks but in the L.Routing section, perhaps this is an innocent issue, just try to assign a default value to self_lat and self_long when declaring them, for example: var self_lat = 0; var self_long = 0;

Comment: Yeah what happens is that the values don't change.